# PySpark ReduceByKey

Tags: python, pyspark

I have been trying to make it work for a while, but failed every time. I have 2 files. One has a list of names:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
```

The other is list of values associated with names for each day in the year over several years:

```
['0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4',
 '0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8', 
 '10,1000,0.2,5000'
  ...]
```

The goal is to have the output like:

```
Name1: [0.1,0.5,10]
Name2: [0.2,0.6,1000]
Name3:[0.3,0.7,0.2]
Name4:[0.4,0.8,5000]
```

And then plot histogram for each. I wrote a mapper that creates a list of tuples that produces the following output (this is an RDD object):

```
[[('Name1', [0.1]),('Name2', [0,2]),('Name3', [0.3]),('Name4', [0.4])],
[('Name1', [0.5]),('Name2', [0,6]),('Name3', [0.7]),('Name4', [0.8])],
[('Name1', [10]),('Name2', [1000]),('Name3', [0.8]),('Name4', [5000])]]
```

Now I need to concatenate all values for each name in a single list, but each map by key, value that I attempted returns a wrong result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply loop through each and create a dictionary from it using [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) . Example -

```
>>> ll = [[('Name1', [0.1]),('Name2', [0,2]),('Name3', [0.3]),('Name4', [0.4])],
... [('Name1', [0.5]),('Name2', [0,6]),('Name3', [0.7]),('Name4', [0.8])],
... [('Name1', [10]),('Name2', [1000]),('Name3', [0.8]),('Name4', [5000])]]
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in ll:
...     for tup in i:
...             d.setdefault(tup[0],[]).extend(tup[1])
...
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'Name1': [0.1, 0.5, 10],
 'Name2': [0, 2, 0, 6, 1000],
 'Name3': [0.3, 0.7, 0.8],
 'Name4': [0.4, 0.8, 5000]}
```

---

For Pyspark RDD Object, try a simple reduce function such as -

```
func = lambda x,y: x+y
```

Then send this in to `reduceByKey` method -

```
object.reduceByKey(func)
```

---

Per comments, actually the OP has a list of RDD Objects (not a single RDD Objects) , in that case you can convert the RDD objects to a list by calling [`.collect()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#collect) and then do the logic , and then you can decide whether you want the resultant as a python dictionary or an RDD object, if you want first. You can call `dict.items()` to get the key-value pairs and call `sc.parrallelize` . Example -

```
d = {}
for i in ll:
    c = i.collect()
    for tup in i:
            d.setdefault(tup[0],[]).extend(tup[1])

rddobj = sc.parallelize(d.items())
```

Comment: the previous result is RDD object, so when I try to apply the function, I get the message that RDD object is not iterable

Comment: I am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reduceByKey'

Comment: Ok I guess I see the picture, you have a list of RDD objects?

Comment: how about you convert each rdd element to a list. Giving example in answer above.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I will try to read a bit more and see if I can figure out a smarter way to solve the problem from what I did.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'collect'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87108/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-anastasia).

Comment: It was a list of lists, so I added for elem in i, skipped c=ii.collect() and the rest is the same. Thanks!